# Returning php content array to string conversion error

Tags: php, html, arrays

I hava a php page where i have a function which does not print or echo to the page it returns a variable called content which is rendered on an html page. Throughout out this function i am appending to the content variable.

i have an array ($myArray) which looks like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2011-11-12 [1] => 1963-02-29 [3] => 2029-05-14 [9] => 1812-08-12 [11] => 1537-05-17  [16] => 2005-17-04  [30] => 3000-42-99  ) )
```

I am trying to loop through each item in $myArray and have it returned to the screen as a h1.

```
  foreach($myArray as $item  ){
    $content .= '<h1>'.$item.'</h1>';
    }
```

This results in me getting an

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

error.

Comment: `$item` is an array, you either need to change how you are building `$myArray`, or you need to iterate once more (or `implode` cleverly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested array , so do like below

```
$arr=array ('0' => array ('0' => '2011-11-12' ,'1' => '1963-02-29' ,'3' => '2029-05-14' ,'9' => '1812-08-12' ,'11' => '1537-05-17'  ,'16' => '2005-17-04'  ,'30' => '3000-42-99')) ;
    foreach($arr as $myArray){
        foreach($myArray as $item  ){
                $content .= '<h1>'.$item.'</h1>';
        }
    }
    echo $content;
```